# サーバ側で、クライアント側の挙動を制御できるのか？

Tags: java

リクエストのurlが、
①サーブレット　のとき
②拡張子がhtml　のとき
③拡張子がtxtやzip　のとき
のそれぞれのパターンに応じて、

Ａ．どのようなレスポンス を作るのか？
Ｂ．クライアントのブラウザでどんな挙動をさせるのか？
を変えたいのですが、
（ダウンロードをさせたり、ダウンロードする際にダイアログボックスで保存先を選ばせたい）

webサーバー側（tomcatの7.0）の設定で、
（なんらかの設定ファイルで）
制御することはできるのでしょうか？

※サーバ側が、クライアント側の挙動に介入するのはできないものなのかなと思っていたのですが、
（イ）webサーバの設定ファイルでコントロール可能なのか、
（ロ）設定ファイルではできないが、サーブレットでのresponseの作り方によってコントロール可能なのか、
（ハ）サーバ側からはコントロール不可能なのか、
どの認識が正しいのでしょうか？

◆補足
使用するサーブレットは１個なので、
web.xmlのurlパターンで処理を振り分けるやり方はできない状況です。
そもそも①のケースにしかならないというのもありますし。。
.

Comment: あなたは「クライアント側の挙動」と言う言葉で何を想定しているのでしょうか?具体的な例を含めて一体何を制御したいのかご説明をお願いします。(ご自身の質問は「編集」できますので、回答を書くために必要な情報は、質問の本文中に追加してください。)なお、あなたは過去のご質問に対する回答やコメントに対してほとんど何のレスポンスも返しておられないようです。回答の中に正答があれば「承認」を、なければご質問を編集するなり、コメントを付けるなりして、回答者が的確な回答をかけるだけの情報を出すようにお願いします。もし、ご自身で解決できた場合には、自己回答してください。

Comment: 現状正確な回答は得られないだろう、というのは既出コメントの通りですが、何となく[Content-Type(のapplication/force-download)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520353/4506703)が所望のものではないかなあ、という気もしました。

Comment: response.setContentType("application/force-download");　がちょうど目的に合致してそうです。クライアントのブラウザの設定を変えた上でテストをやってみようと思いますが、幾分、知識が少ないところがありますので、上手くいったかどうかのご報告は少し間を置いてから改めて致します。ありがとうございます！